# What is the purpose of this magic number?

Tags: actionscript-3, random, magic-numbers

The following snippet of code is taken from [a Pseudo-random number generator (written in ActionScript 3)](https://github.com/gskinner/AS3Libs/blob/master/Rndm/com/gskinner/utils/Rndm.as#L127):

```
public function random():Number {
    _currentSeed = (_currentSeed * 16807) % 2147483647);
    return (_currentSeed/0x7FFFFFFF) + 0.000000000233;
}
```

The first line of the code is easy to understand, it's a standard [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), with the multiplier being `16807`. The first part of the second line converts the resulting integer to a float roughly between `0` and `1`.

However, what is the purpose of that last part of the second line, `+ 0.000000000233`? Is it necessary in such an RNG, or does it serve a different purpose?

Comment: I have this marked for AS3, but I'm sure the question applies to many other programming languages as well.

Comment: Psstt never ask about magic; it's magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk of the algorithm is a [well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) prime modulus multiplicative linear congruential generator. All those prefix adjectives mean that it achieves maximum cycle length without the additive term that generalized [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)s have, so PMMLCGs were popular dating back to the 1950's because you did one less operation per invocation. You should never initialize `_currentSeed` to zero, and the algorithm is designed to never yield a zero or negative number if properly implemented and seeded because it's based on integer arithmetic, which is precise.  (Proper implementation means insuring the results aren't affected by integer overflow.  A portable algorithm to do this was written in FORTRAN by Linus Schrage back in 1959, along with a simple test consisting of what the seed value ought to be after 1000 iterations.)

The magic number is slightly bigger than `(1/2) / 0x7fffffff`, so it shouldn't push the return value up over 1.  Since it's not being added to `_currentSeed`, it plays no role in avoiding the fixed-point behavior that would happen if `_currentSeed` was ever set to zero. Honestly, I can't see that it is accomplishing much of anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the rest of the formula, you'll see that a `_currentSeed` value of `0` will always result in the same value of `0`. Adding `(0.5/0x7fffffff)`, prevents it from ever getting stuck on `0`, but is small enough to also prevent it from returning a value `>= 1`.

To be fair, I wrote that code more than 6 years ago, so I might be remembering wrong, but I'm fairly certain that's the reasoning.

Comment: Well, that would theoretically make sense, however, the value `0.000000000233` is never actually added to the value of `_currentSeed`, it is only added to the float returned by the function. In fact, if `_currentSeed` is ever set to `0`, it will still continue to return `0` all the time anyway, even with your "safeguard" in place.

Answer (score -1):

I think, for some reason, `_currentSeed` could be a negative value because `_currentSeed` is a signed integer. Adding `0.000000000233` (`0.5/0x7fffffff`) to the value could avoid this situation.

Comment: Well, actually, looking at the rest of the code that I linked to, `_currentSeed` is an **unsigned** integer. Even if it was signed, and was ever negative, adding such a tiny value would never be enough of a push to make it positive.